# Running additional filter on queryset triggers database hits

Tags: django

I have a method that retrieves all records from a model for one give date and uses the result to run additional filtering. The additional filtering is a loop that retrieves records hour by  hour.

Simplified example (some pseudo coding in the example)

```
qs = Occasion.filter(start_date__gte='2013-05-27 00:00:00', end_date__lte='2013-05-27 23:59:59')

list(qs)

for start_hour, end_hour in method_that_returns_hour_for_date('2013-05-27 00:00:00'):        
    # start_hour = 2013-05-27 00:00:00
    # end_hour = 2013-05-27 01:00:00 and so on...

    #The query below renders a new query
    sub = qs.filter(start_date__lte=start_hour, end_date__gte=end_hour)
```

In debug toolbar I can see that for each hour in the loop a new DB query is done. I have tried to trigger the SQL query to be executed before the loop by doing a len() on the unfiltered queryset and also a list() but this doesn't prevent additional queries to be executed when looping.

What can I do to optimize this?

Comment: The only way would be to load all objects into memory and access it from there, if less database queries is the requirement for optimization.

Comment: `qs = Occasion.filter(start_date__gte='2013-05-27 00:00:00', end_date__lte='2013-05-27 23:59:59')` is unnecessary.

Comment: The reason why I am doing the "unnecessary" filtering is because I was hoping to load all objects into memory for the given day to avoid hitting the DB for each hour.

Comment: Actually, I don't see such issue. `qs.filter` does not go to DB. Is there anyother code that can affect this?

Comment: @Rohan he said he was pseudo coding.